# footer item qml issue

Tags: qt, qml

I am trying to build an app for my school project, so here what i want to do :

- first m using footer property to position my buttom button on it but when i try to do left margin to get with the same culumn as my leftbutton i have no result
- and i get the same probleme when i try to double click my window , my left button let so much space

[image]

[image]

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts



ApplicationWindow {
    id: applicationWindow
    property string displayedButton: ""
    width: 800
        height: 380
    visible: true

    Page {
        anchors.fill: parent
        id:page

        RowLayout {
            id:rec
            anchors.fill: parent


            ListView {
                anchors.topMargin: 20
                y:10
                id: leftMenuBar
                Layout.preferredWidth: 90
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                clip: true
                spacing: 10
                Repeater {
                    model: 3
                    delegate: Button{
                        implicitHeight: 90
                        implicitWidth: 90
                        text: "Button " + (index + 1)
                        onClicked: displayedButton = text



                        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter // must be set to align the rectangles within their empty space
                    }
                }

                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft
                Layout.leftMargin: 20
            }

            Item {
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true

                Rectangle {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    anchors.margins: 12
                    border.width: 2
                    border.color: "lightgray"
                    radius: 35

                    Text {
                        anchors.centerIn: parent
                        text: "Selected Button: " + displayedButton
                        font.pixelSize: 20
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        footer:RowLayout {
            width: 500



            Repeater {
                model: 8
                delegate: Button{
                    implicitHeight: 90
                    implicitWidth: 90
                    text: "Button " + (index + 1)
                    onClicked: displayedButton = text



                    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter // must be set to align the rectangles within their empty space
                }
            }
        }






    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem entierly. If you want to align your bottom buttons with the rectangle don't put the buttons in the footer but use a GridLayout.

```
Page {
    anchors.fill: parent
    id:page

    GridLayout {
        id:rec
        anchors.fill: parent
        columns: 2

        ListView {
            anchors.topMargin: 20
            y:10
            id: leftMenuBar
            Layout.preferredWidth: 90
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            clip: true
            spacing: 10
            Repeater {
                model: 3
                delegate: Button{
                    implicitHeight: 90
                    implicitWidth: 90
                    text: "Button " + (index + 1)
                    onClicked: displayedButton = text



                    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter // must be set to align the rectangles within their empty space
                }
            }

            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignLeft
            Layout.leftMargin: 20
        }

        Item {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true

            Rectangle {
                anchors.fill: parent
                anchors.margins: 12
                border.width: 2
                border.color: "lightgray"
                radius: 35

                Text {
                    anchors.centerIn: parent
                    text: "Selected Button: " + displayedButton
                    font.pixelSize: 20
                }
            }
        }

        // Placeholder item to align footer buttons
        Item {

        }

        RowLayout {
            Repeater {
                model: 8
                delegate: Button{
                    implicitHeight: 90
                    implicitWidth: 90
                    text: "Button " + (index + 1)
                    onClicked: displayedButton = text

                    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter // must be set to align the rectangles within their empty space
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: GridLayout]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want it to stretch, you have some choices:

1. Use `Row` instead of `RowLayout`, OR
2. Use a dummy `Item { Layout.fillWidth: true }` inside your `RowLayout` immediately after your `Repeater`